# [CocoaPods error]: Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: cocoapods, apple-m1

I have a CocoaPods error on my Mac M1. the following error from Cocoapods:Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass".

Answer (score 4):

I solve this issue on my Mac M1 by typing this in the terminal:

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Comment: Why is this working?

Answer (score 4):

Solve this by run this command

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If i run "arch -x86_64 pod install" i get the error "No Podfile found". Why? I already in the folder where i run "npx react-native init"